# How to get reloadData to work on UITableView

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a UITableView that loads from a NIB file. The controller for the screen is a subclass of UIViewController that conforms to the UITableView delegate protocols. This is the 2nd screen in a stack of views managed by a UINavigationController.

In my viewWillAppear for the offending view I run two NSFetchRequests and update 2 of the 3 sections in my table with results from those NSFetchRequests. At the bottom of viewWillAppear I call

```
[self.myTable reloadData];
```

myTable is an IBOutlet to the UITableView for the screen.

For whatever reason the table doesn't reload the data and none of the delegate methods for the table get called when I come back up to it from views deeper in the Navigation Controller hierarchy.

How do I get the table to reload?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked that myTable is not nil? have you also checked that table's dataSource and delegate are not nil? don't forget the "messages to nil" rule of Cocoa!

Comment: What happens when you message to nil?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Instead of self.tableView, use:

```
[myTable reloadData];
```

So if you defined your IBOulet as **myTable**, then you need to use that name instead.

self.myTable would work if you initialized myTable like in your header:

```
self.myTable = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

Comment: This worked. Isn't [self.myTable reloadData] and [myTable reloadData] the same thing. Is it because self.myTable calls the setters and getters?

Answer (score 1):

Have you also linked the UITableView to data source and delegate outlets in the nib file? You have to link these two in addition to the IBOutlet.